# What's happening if one of concurent lock on a table rename the locked table?

Tags: database, postgresql

I've hundred of insert as following each minutes:

```
BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

  INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (...);

COMMIT;
```

And I've the following transaction which will occured once:

```
BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

  LOCK TABLE table1 IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;

  /* Rename the locked table */
  ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO table1_renamed;

  /* And I recreate the table */
  CREATE TABLE table1 (
    ...
  );

COMMIT;
```

The second transaction will blocked all INSERTs until it commits.

When it commits, will inserts be proceed on the new `table1` or on the renamed one?

In other world are locks acquired on object's name (so it's resilient on rename operation) or on object's reference?

Comment: Because (almost all of) the DDL statements can be rolled back in PostgreSQL, I think the insertion will happen in the old table. Unless this causes a serialization failure, because the [`SERIALIZABLE` isolation is the strictest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) (but the docs doesn't mention DDL statements explicitly).

Comment: You *may* achieve a more reliable behavior with `CREATE TABLE new_t AS SELECT * FROM old_t; DELETE FROM old_t;`

Comment: @pozs But the new table need to get the name of the old one

Comment: That's the point. In my suggestion, the `new_t` will be *your* old one (i.e. the one, which will actually contain rows) and `old_t` (which has the old name) will be empty, just like a newly created table would.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm affraid that the values will be inserted into the new table (if possible, of course). It's not what one should expect. Indeed, the documentation is not clear in this issue.

Comment: So, you want to duplicate data too? Then just don't use delete. Just create a new table & copy data to there. That won't have any issue with transactions at all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to mock your doubts. session one `t=# \set PROMPT1 1>`, session two `t=# \set PROMPT1 2>`. `--N` after semicolon means sequential statement number to run into your described situation:

session one:

```
1>BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; --2
BEGIN
1>ALTER TABLE so32 rename to so33;--4
ALTER TABLE
1>create table so32(i int,t timestamptz default now());--7
CREATE TABLE
1>end;--9
COMMIT
```

session two:

```
2>BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; --1
BEGIN
2>insert into so32 (i) select 2;--3
INSERT 0 1
2>end;--5
COMMIT
2>BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; --6
BEGIN
2>insert into so32 (i) select 2;--8
INSERT 0 1
2>end;--10
COMMIT
2>select * from so32;
 i |               t
---+-------------------------------
 2 | 2017-03-23 15:31:41.770094+00
(1 row)

2>select * from so33;
 i |               t
---+-------------------------------
 2 | 2017-03-23 15:30:50.761371+00
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

All transactions that queue after the `LOCK TABLE` will get the new table and `INSERT` into it:

```
s1=> CREATE TABLE table1 (id integer PRIMARY KEY, val text NOT NULL);
s1=> BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
s1=> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 'one');

s2=> BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
s2=> LOCK TABLE table1 IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;  -- blocks

s2=> BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
s3=> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, 'two');  -- blocks, queues behind s2

s1=> COMMIT;  -- unblocks s2

s2=> ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO table1_renamed;
s2=> CREATE TABLE table1 (id integer PRIMARY KEY, val text NOT NULL);
s2=> COMMIT;  --unblocks s3

s3=> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, 'two');
s3=> COMMIT;
```

The row inserted by session `s3` is in the new table:

```
s1=> SELECT * FROM table1;
┌────┬─────┐
│ id │ val │
├────┼─────┤
│  2 │ two │
└────┴─────┘
(1 row)
```